# Isoclinism for Lie groups: existing accounts of basic properties?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Philip Hall introduced the relation of *isoclinism* between two groups. One statement of the definition (not Hall's original statement) is to introduce a category whose objects are the canonical maps 
$$c_G: G/Z(G) \times G/Z(G) \to G'\quad; \quad c_G( xZ(G), yZ(G) ) = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$$
and where a morphism from $c_G$ to $c_H$ is given by a pair of group homomorphisms $(G/Z(G) \to H/Z(H),\, G' \to H')$ that make the obvious square commute.

Note that every group homomorphism $\theta:G\to H$ gives rise to a morphism $c_G\to c_H$, but we don't require every morphism $c_G\to c_H$ to be of this form.

We say that $G$ and $H$ are *isoclinic* if $c_G$ and $c_H$ are isomorphic in this category. Every abelian group is isoclinic to the trivial one; more generally, if I understand the literature correctly, the derived series of two isoclinic groups (not necessarily finite) have the same length.

For reasons motivated by noncommutative harmonic analysis, I was wondering if Hall's notion had ever been taken up in the setting of Lie groups (with the natural choice of morphisms, and defining $G'$ as the kernel of $G \to G_{ab}$). To my surprise, a quick search online did not show me any sources discussing this. In particular, one would expect that requiring two connected Lie groups to be isoclinic says something about their adjoint representations and hence about their Lie algebras, but I have not yet sat down to work through the details.

My question is this: are there any sources/articles that describe the basic properties of isoclinism in the world of Lie groups, or which make use of the fact that two groups are isoclinic to say something about their Lie algebras?

It might be the case that "there are some obvious statements which are easy to check; there are facts from the setting of finite groups, which extend in the obvious way by adding the right adjectives; and beyond that there is little to say." But if anyone knows of references in the literature, which would save me needlessly repeating straightforward calculations, that would be helpful.